# Python Selenium submit works only in debug mode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, debugging, form-submit, webdriverwait

My python program with selenium has a strange behavior : it works very good when I start it in debug mode but not in normal mode. The FromDate is not taken into account in normal mode.

I thought it was a timing problem and I put several wait (explicit and implicit wait) with no difference. Note that the button is a submit and not a click.
Any Idea to solve this issue ?

```
url = "https://my.elexys.be/MarketInformation/SpotBelpex.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
FromDate = driver.find_element("name", "ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$fromASPxDateEdit")
FromDate.clear()
FromDate.send_keys("01/11/2023")
UntilDate = driver.find_element("name", "ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$untilASPxDateEdit")
UntilDate.clear()
UntilDate.send_keys("01/12/2023")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$refreshBelpexCustomButton")))
ShowData_button = driver.find_element("name", "ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$refreshBelpexCustomButton")
ShowData_button.submit()
```

Comment: maybe first check what you get in `driver.page_source`. Maybe server sends different content - ie. some warning or captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Your clicking on show data button too fast - changes are entered, but not applied as an input event.

To simulate input event more close to user flow, I suggest to add smth like pressing enter.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = "https://my.elexys.be/MarketInformation/SpotBelpex.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get(url)
FromDate = driver.find_element("name", "ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$fromASPxDateEdit")
FromDate.clear()
FromDate.send_keys("01/11/2023")
action_chains.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

UntilDate = driver.find_element("name", "ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$untilASPxDateEdit")
UntilDate.clear()
UntilDate.send_keys("01/12/2023")
action_chains.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$refreshBelpexCustomButton")))
ShowData_button = driver.find_element("name", "ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$refreshBelpexCustomButton")
ShowData_button.submit()
```

Comment: @JeanMarcCanon can you plz check this answer as "correct" if it resolves your issue? :)